# Allow decryption key to be known only after a certain time

Tags: cryptography, encryption

We have a smart contract containing encrypted data that should remain encrypted till a specified timeLimit.
Then, the decryption key would be made public, for everyone to read that data.
We want to achieve this in a trustless manner, as anyone with knowledge of this data before the timeLimit can use it to exploit the system.

How can this be achieved?

PS:
I tried exploring "proof of work" based "time lock puzzle" solutions. (related: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/606/time-capsule-cryptography)
But I find these unreliable, as its possible for a miner to find a solution before timeLimit and only reveal it later.
Also, if you set the difficulty hard enough, then there may not be any solution found for a long time even after timeLimit, which is also bad.

Comment: The simplest way would be to use [Ownable](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/98c3a79b5765d58ef27856b8211c70a4907c63be/contracts/access/Ownable.sol) and have an [onlyOwner](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/98c3a79b5765d58ef27856b8211c70a4907c63be/contracts/access/Ownable.sol#L35-L38)-protected method that lets the owner disclose the decryption key at the right time. Though this wouldn't be a "trustless" solution.

Comment: yeah trust is the issue. Even owner cant be trusted and he himself can exploit the knowledge of this decryption key. If maybe there is some standard third party agency doing this secret keeping offchain?